# Can't add dictionaries with nil values to array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsdictionary

I am trying to create dictionary like here:

```
var dicItem = ["dataOfChange": 21-01-2012, "item": nil, "orderer": nil, "song": 1, "itemId": 3447, "petro": nil]
```

I create `dicItem` in a `loop` and in loop when create `dicItem` I want to add it to the array:
`array.append(serStatdicItemusJSON)` 
This is my array:

```
var data = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

But I am getting following error when try to add to array:

```
fatal error: attempt to bridge an implicitly unwrapped optional containing nil
```

I think that this is becouse of nil's but can't figure how to solve it.

Comment: Your `dicItem` is of a type `[String, Int]` since you are not using `""`. Is that just a typo on your part or are there no `""` in your code either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item in a dictionary needs to be an `object`. `nil` is not an object, and that's why you got the error.

There is a couple of solutions:

1. use `if` statement to check if a value is `nil`. Only add the key/value pair to the dictionary when the value is not `nil`.
2. use `NSNull`, which is an object, instead of `nil`.
3. write a function converting `nil` to `empty string ("")`, and calling the function every time you want to add something to the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You should set type as `[String:AnyObject?]`

```
var dicItem: [String:AnyObject?] = ["dataOfChange": 21-01-2012, "item": nil, "orderer": nil, "song": 1, "itemId": 3447, "petro": nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary)."

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html)